# Insert into a set based on a sequence of coin flips. Conditional probability?

Tags: probability

I am studying for an exam and found the following problem.

> Let $L = l_0, l_1, ... , l_{n+1}$ be a
>   list of items.  For each item from 0
>   to $n+1$, we flip a coin (fairly).  We add
>   item $l_i$ (with $1 \le i \le n$) to a set if $l_i$'s toss came
>   up heads, and both of its neighbours
>   ($l_{i - 1}$ and $l_{i + 1}$) came up
>   tails.  What is the probability that
>   $l_i$ is included in the set?

My initial thought is that it is simply 1/8.  The probability that the coin is heads is 1/2, the one before it being tails has probability 1/2, and the same idea for the toss after it.  Am I missing something, or is it really that simple?  They are obviously dependent on one another.

Comment: I can't parse "We add item l_i to a set of l_i's toss came up heads".

Comment: Yes it is (that simple). Of course, joint laws are more complicated, for instance two neighbors cannot both be chosen.

Comment: @Alon Amit:  Wow, sorry.  Must be early.  If the toss came up heads

Comment: There seems to be a slight mistake in the problem statement. If coins are only flipped for items $1$ to $n$, then there's no coin for $0$ and $n+1$ to use in deciding whether to include $1$ and $n$. It looks like what they meant is that a coin is flipped for each item from $0$ to $n+1$, and then the decision rule is applied for each item from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: @shoes: it's not just the missing "if" - I don't understand what's the role of the "items" in the problem and what "adding l_i to a set of l_i's" means. I guess I can imagine what this is trying to say but since you're asking if there's any subtlety here, you really ought to make the question very precise.

Comment: @joriki: I hope my edit improves the question.  *if/of* also changed

Comment: @Alon Amit:  The role of items are as a generic 'term'.  We could think of them themselves as coin tosses (rather than having a coin toss associated with it) and if toss i-1 and i+1 are tails, while toss i is heads, then we write that toss number down on a piece of paper.  What is the probability that it is written on the paper? (and following from that, what are the expected number of tosses written on the page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the whole question, yes, it really is that simple.  Perhaps there's a part (b)...

On the other hand, maybe this is intended to test the student's ability to filter out irrelevant aspects of the problem.  This is actually a significant issue with many probability students, who might insist on using a sample space involving all $n+2$ coin flips.

Comment: You're right.  There is a part b.  It is to compute the expected size of the list.  This seems trivial if you're given the probability, though.

Comment: @joriki: But, by linearity of expectation, shouldn't this still be n/8?  How does the conditionality of this change the problem?

Comment: @shoes: $n/8$ look right to me.  The dependency might affect the variance, but it should not affect the expectation.

Comment: @shoes, @Henry: Sorry, I've deleted my braindead comment about the expectation value being influenced by the correlations.